# Sending all messages from one queue to another

Tags: activemq-classic

Is it possible to send all messages from one queue to another using only ActiveMQ console? For example, I have queue A with 1000 messages and queue B with 0 messages. Is there some button, command, or something to send all 1000 messages from queue A to queue B?

Comment: Are you asking about ActiveMQ 5.x or ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: Apache ActiveMQ 5.x